# Rename multiple files in ternimal?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, terminal

I have a bunch of files in the following format

xx.xx - blah blah blah blah

Where xx is a number. I need to remove the xx.xx - so I am just left with the text. Is there a way to mass rename files in terminal using regex? I have seen some bash one liners on previous answers but not sure how to mold them for what I need. I tried

```
rename -v -n 's/\d{2}\.\d{2}\s-\s//' ./*
```

but couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `rename` command:

```
rename -v -n 's/^\d{2}\.\d{2} *- *//' [0-9]*
```

Comment: Hmm, that is what I wanted but diddnt work for what I needed. Would there be a way to instead change
 xx.xx - Blah 
to
 SxxExx - Blah

Comment: For example 01.06 - Death.mp4 renaming to S01E06 - Death.mp4. I tried what you posted and it diddnt seem to work.

Comment: Try this: `rename -v -n 's/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})(.+)$/S$1E$2$3/' [0-9]*`